# Reading the text file is not working in decryption, where i am going wrong here?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, c#-2.0

I have created an Encryption method to encrypt the data into `test.txt` Text file. The encryption is Working fine and its Reading the encryted text file into `textBox1`.

I m using 2 buttons and 2 textBox for doing this.

Now I want to `Read` the decryption text from `test.txt` in `textBox2`
but when i click on the button to read data from `test.txt` to `textBox2`.

I am getting an exception like `(CryptographicException was unhandled) Bad Data`.

Here is the code I used for Dycryption.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt",
                          FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
        cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

        CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
            cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream);
        //string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

        textBox2.Text = reader.ReadLine();
        //stream.Close();
    }
```

**Codes that i used for Encrytion is here:**

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
        cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

        CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
           cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);


        byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);

        crStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        crStream.Close();
        stream.Close();
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C://test.txt");
        textBox1.Text = text.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: Post the actual exception stack trace, as well as your encryption code.

Comment: (CryptographicException was unhandled) Bad Data

Comment: i added encryption method too, that how I encryted the texts into text file.

Comment: You can't read in the cipher data as a text file and store it in a string. That will lose information. If you need it to be human-readable text then use base64 encoding, available in the System.Convert class.

Comment: OK. So i can't read it all?

Comment: You can read it all, you cannot just convert it to a string; not all bytes are valid character encodings and if they are they may not be printable. Try to base 64 encode/decode the ciphertext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to read it from test.txt file. when your displaying it in textbox. but check below code you can able to encrypt and decry-pt and meanwhile able to display and save in text boxes.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        string datastring=    Encrypt("ABCDEFGH", "ABCDEFGH");


        byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(datastring);

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\test.txt");
        TextBox1.Text = text.ToString();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         StreamReader reader =null;
        try
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt",
                       FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
           string fileContents;
           using ( reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
            string data = Decrypt(fileContents, "ABCDEFGH");

            TextBox2.Text = data;

            stream.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(data));
            stream.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }

    }

    public static string Encrypt(string message, string password)
    {
        // Encode message and password
        byte[] messageBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        byte[] passwordBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

        // Set encryption settings -- Use password for both key and init. vector
        DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(passwordBytes, passwordBytes);
        CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

        // Set up streams and encrypt
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, transform, mode);
        cryptoStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Read the encrypted message from the memory stream
        byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Position = 0;
        memStream.Read(encryptedMessageBytes, 0, encryptedMessageBytes.Length);

        // Encode the encrypted message as base64 string
        string encryptedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedMessageBytes);

        return encryptedMessage;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string encryptedMessage, string password)
    {
        // Convert encrypted message and password to bytes
        byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedMessage);
        byte[] passwordBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

        // Set encryption settings -- Use password for both key and init. vector
        DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateDecryptor(passwordBytes, passwordBytes);
        CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

        // Set up streams and decrypt
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, transform, mode);
        cryptoStream.Write(encryptedMessageBytes, 0, encryptedMessageBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Read decrypted message from memory stream
        byte[] decryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Position = 0;
        memStream.Read(decryptedMessageBytes, 0, decryptedMessageBytes.Length);

        // Encode deencrypted binary data to base64 string
        string message = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedMessageBytes);

        return message;
    }
```